# Scrolling up to the topmost in iOS's Safari causes problems with scrolling-up/down detection

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

I have the following Javascript code:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
        let scrollStatus = $(this).scrollTop();

        if (scrollStatus > lastScrollTop) {
            //do some stuffs

        else
            //do some other stuffs

        lastScrollTop = scrollStatus;
    }
});
```

So it worked well with non-mobile devices and Android devices. However, when I ran that on iOS's Safari and scroll to the topmost, it drags down the viewport by a little bit before bouncing up back when I release my finger hold. That bounce back up is detected by the above Javascript code as scrolling up and causes the trigger on the `else` section, which is undesirable. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before bouncing back Safari overscrolls the Y-Position into negative land. You can use this to ignore position changes from the bounce animation.

The window scroll event fires very rapidly. For performance reasons you don't want to handle these events directly.

The example below shows how to check in 250ms intervals whether the user has scrolled, which is easy on performance.

```
var didScroll = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {
  didScroll = true;
});

// interval scroll handler
setInterval(function() {
  if ( didScroll ) {
    didScroll = false;
    scrolled();
  }
}, 250);

var lastScrollTop = 0;

function scrolled() {
  var scrollStatus = window.pageYOffset;

  if (scrollStatus < lastScrollTop) {
      //user scrolled up
  } else if ( lastScrollTop >= 0) {
      //user scrolled down
  }
  lastScrollTop = scrollStatus;
}
```

Alternatively you can alleviate performance issues by resetting a timeout that only calls the scrolled() function after scrolling has finished.

```
var timer;

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ( timer ) clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(function(){
    scrolled();
  }, 100);
});

var lastScrollTop = 0;

function scrolled() {
  var scrollStatus = window.pageYOffset;

  if (scrollStatus < lastScrollTop) {
      //user scrolled up
  } else if ( lastScrollTop >= 0) {
      //user scrolled down
  }
  lastScrollTop = scrollStatus;
}
```

Comment: I see! I also suspected that the lag was caused by my scrolling script. Thank you for pointing it out. Do you reckon I should also `setInterval` for my `resize` script?

Comment: And what about the `lastScrollTop` initial value? Still `0`?

Comment: Yes,lastScrollTop should be initialised at 0, see my edit.
I'm not sure what your resize script does, but if it is triggered by scrolling then yes.

Comment: Sorry, by 'resize', I meant something like `$(window).resize(function() { //do something });`

Comment: Learnt something new again: `setTimeout` :-D Thanks! It's even better than `setInterval`.

Comment: @WealthyPlayer Yes, the window.resize event has similar performance issues, that also require slowing it down, aka "debouncing" the event. https://www.paulirish.com/2009/throttled-smartresize-jquery-event-handler/